# How to add System.Web.Mvc version 5 to the project references

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, reference, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget-package

When I want to add System.Web.Mvc by right clicking the project and Add>Reference option, there is only version 3.0.0.0 and 4.0.0.0. However, I created the project as MVC 5. On the other hand, trying to add this reference on Nuget Package, there is no reference with the same name. Instead of this, there is another refernce named So:

1) How can add System.Web.Mvc (version 5 or later) reference to my projects including Class Library?

2) What is the difference between **System.Web.Mvc** and **Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.0.0) for MVC 5. If you look at the bottom of the website, you can find links to other versions as well.

Comment: Actually I see the later version on https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/, but I am not sure if this reference contains all the features of System.Web.Mvc. Any idea?

Comment: @Christof , thank you! Yes, it has reference to system.web.mvc version 5.2.3.0 today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.Web.Mvc` Is one of the core namespaces developed by MS,it  contains classes and interfaces that support the ASP.NET Model View Controller (MVC) framework for creating Web applications. This namespace includes classes that represent controllers, controller factories, action results, views, partial view, model binders, and much more. [MS Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Don't get confused with another namespace: `Microsoft.Web.Mvc`which contains classes that support the `ASP.NET.MVC` framework for creating web applications.

Now back to your first question about `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`that you can download from Nuget. I think it's the same as `System.web.mvc` , if you check  dll file it creates, you will notice that it has the exact samedll name: `System.Web.Mvc.dll`. It has the same size, assembly signature, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this odd issue and had to uninstall/reinstall Microsoft ASP.NET MVC via NuGet Package Manager - for the project in question - before I could add the correct System.Web.Mvc v5.0.